# Converting A javascript Http Upload script to Curl command

Tags: javascript, curl

I have a device which has this javascript function on it's web interface:

```
function upload() {
    $( "#progress" ).empty();
    $( "#uploadresult" ).empty();

    // take the file from the input
    var file = document.getElementById('files').files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsBinaryString(file); // alternatively you can use readAsDataURL
    reader.onloadend  = function(evt)
    {
        // create XHR instance
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        // send the file through POST
        xhr.open("POST", 'upload', true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Filename', file.name);

        // make sure we have the sendAsBinary method on all browsers
        XMLHttpRequest.prototype.mySendAsBinary = function(text){
            var data = new ArrayBuffer(text.length);
            var ui8a = new Uint8Array(data, 0);
            for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) ui8a[i] = (text.charCodeAt(i) & 0xff);

            if(typeof window.Blob == "function")
            {
                 var blob = new Blob([data]);
            }else{
                 var bb = new (window.MozBlobBuilder || window.WebKitBlobBuilder || window.BlobBuilder)();
                 bb.append(data);
                 var blob = bb.getBlob();
            }

            this.send(blob);
        }

        // let's track upload progress
        var eventSource = xhr.upload || xhr;
        eventSource.addEventListener("progress", function(e) {
            // get percentage of how much of the current file has been sent
            var position = e.position || e.loaded;
            var total = e.totalSize || e.total;
            var percentage = Math.round((position/total)*100);

            // here you should write your own code how you wish to proces this
            $( "#progress" ).empty().append('uploaded ' + percentage + '%');
        });

        // state change observer - we need to know when and if the file was successfully uploaded
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if(xhr.readyState == 4)
            {
                if(xhr.status == 200)
                {
                    // process success
                    $( "#uploadresult" ).empty().append( 'Uploaded Ok');
                }else{
                    // process error
                    $( "#uploadresult" ).empty().append( 'Uploaded Failed');
                }
            }
        };

        // start sending
        xhr.mySendAsBinary(evt.target.result);
    };
}
```

seems to me like it's using POST to upload files and I'm trying to upload files to it using CURL command line and it keeps failing on me, here is the command I'm using:
    curl -F "FileUpload=@build.txt" myipaddress/upload

and it gives me :FAILED   (it's coming from the server)

what is wrong?!

Comment: dear friend, that is javascript.

Comment: okay?! I know it's java, I have said that in the first line. But I want to do the same thing that this script is doing with CURL  ( I don't need all the progress percentage and other crap that is in the code) I just know that this code works for uploading to the server and that's why I put it here

Comment: JavaScript and Java are entirely different things.

Comment: I'm sorry for miss interpreting, I totally have no knowledge about any of them and that's why I'm asking for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so let's step through this.

The url that the script is posting the data to is denoted by this line:

`xhr.open("POST", 'upload', true);`

So, we know the endpoint you need to hit is yourdomain.com/upload

We see from this line:

`xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Filename', file.name);`

That the request is sending a header with the file's name, so we'll be sure to include that too.

We also see that it is encoding the text as binary before it sends, so we'll just send the actual file and not try to read the text or anything first.

So, putting it all together, and you get something like this:

`curl -H "X-Filename: yourFileName" -X POST -d @yourFileName http://yourdomain.com/upload`

Note that the url may be replaced with `ipaddress/upload` in case you're doing this locally and don't have host files set up. You might need a PORT too, depending on your configuration and if you're doing this locally. That would look like: `ipaddress:port/upload`

Comment: Oh, right! I just needed the -H! Thank you very much!